# how to upload file in Jmeter

Tags: file-upload, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, stress-testing

how to upload file in Jmeter? when .txt file body data contain extra special characters and extra lines server throwing 400 Bad request. if body data contain simple "Hello World" am able to upload file into the server. can you please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is just record your file upload event using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder)

1. Configure JMeter for Recording, the fastest way is using JMeter Templates Feature

   - From JMeter's main menu choose `File -> Templates -> Recording` and click "Create"
   - Expand `Workbench -> HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder` and click "Start"
2. Copy the file you want to upload to "bin" folder of your JMeter installation
3. Configure your browser to use JMeter as a proxy
4. Perform upload in browser - JMeter will generate relevant [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler under `Test Plan -> Thread Group -> Recording Controller`

More information: [Recording File Uploads with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/recording-file-uploads-jmeter)

Comment: Hi Dmitri i have completed recording all the things but when am uploading .txt file body data contain extra special characters and extra lines server throwing 400 Bad request. if body data contain simple "Hello World" am able to upload file into the server